# Leaderboard in Flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have a leaderboard made with firebase. I'm currently looking for users. And I want it to show when a user is found what place they are in the leaderboard. Does anyone know how to do this?

If anything, here is the code for the leaderboard:

```
FutureBuilder(
        future: FirebaseFirestore.instance
            .collection('users')
            .orderBy('balance', descending: true)
            .limit(100)
            .get(),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return loading();
          }

          return ListView.separated(
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                double moneys = double.parse(
                    snapshot.data?.docs[index].get('balance').toString() ??
                        '0');

                return Container(
                  width: double.infinity,
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, right: 15.0),
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      color: Colors.white,
                      border: (index + 1) == 1 ||
                              (index + 1) == 2 ||
                              (index + 1) == 3
                          ? Border.all(
                              color: Colors.orangeAccent, width: 2.0)
                          : null,
                      boxShadow: [
                        BoxShadow(
                            color: (index + 1) == 1 ||
                                    (index + 1) == 2 ||
                                    (index + 1) == 3
                                ? Colors.orangeAccent.withOpacity(0.5)
                                : Colors.black.withOpacity(0.3),
                            blurRadius: 10.0)
                      ]),
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                      child: Row(
                        children: [
                          AutoSizeText(
                            '#${(index + 1)}',
                            style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                color: Colors.black87,
                                fontSize: 25.0,
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                          ),
                          const SizedBox(width: 15.0),
                          Column(
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                            children: [
                              AutoSizeText(
                                snapshot.data?.docs[index].get('name') ??
                                    '',
                                style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                    color: Colors.black87,
                                    fontSize: 23.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w900),
                              ),
                              const SizedBox(height: 5.0),
                              AutoSizeText(
                                moneys < 1000000
                                    ? NumberFormat.simpleCurrency(
                                            locale: ui.Platform.localeName)
                                        .format(moneys)
                                    : NumberFormat.compactSimpleCurrency(
                                            locale: ui.Platform.localeName)
                                        .format(moneys),
                                style: GoogleFonts.roboto(
                                    color: Colors.black87,
                                    fontSize: 18.0,
                                    fontWeight: FontWeight.w700),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      )),
                );
              },
              separatorBuilder: (contex, index) =>
                  const SizedBox(height: 15.0),
              itemCount: snapshot.data?.docs.length ?? 0);
        }),
```

Ignore this text, it's for StackOverflow. He writes that my post is mostly code. Ignore this text, it's for StackOverflow. He writes that my post is mostly code. Ignore this text, it's for StackOverflow. He writes that my post is mostly code.

Comment: Can you clarify what's being asked? Is there an issue with the code in the question? If so, what is the issue? Which line is not working as intended. Please take a moment and review [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Jay, I'll try to explain it again. I have a screen with a leaderboard and also, at the top, I have a text box where I can enter a user's nickname and find it. Once found, I get some information about him, but that's not the main thing. The main thing is that I want to be shown on what place he is in the table of leaders. How to do it?

Comment: You've tagged the question with Firebase/Firestore but it doesn't sound like that's related. But maybe it is? Are you asking how to create a query to retrieve users or a particular user? When you say "on what place he is" are you talking about some kind of ranking system you need to sort? Or is the question about how you display a table of data in the UI? Or something else entirely?